# How to skip fragments of code in Matrix?

Tags: matrix

I fell like I'm missing an obvious thing, how to end block before I will start the new one?

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}

{% if block.type == "heading" %}

    <h3>{{ block.heading }}</h3>
    <h1>I don't want this text to be part of heading block</h1>

{% elseif block.type == "text" %}

    {{ block.text|markdown }}

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

## edit: here is my real code:

```
{# "Check" section #}
                    <section class="wrapper style1 container special">
                        <div class="row">
{# "Check" block #}
            {% elseif block.type == "check" %}
                            <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
                                <section>
                                    <span class="icon featured fa-check"></span>
                                    <header>
                                        <h3>{{ block.checkHeader }}</h3>
                                    </header>
                                    <p>{{ block.checkText }}</p>
                                </section>
                            </div>
{# In this place block "check" should end #}
                        </div>
                    </section>
{# end of "check" section#}

{#beginning of "gallery section" #}
                        <section class="wrapper style3 container special">
                        <header class="major">
                            <h2>Next look at this <strong>cool stuff</strong></h2>
                        </header>

                        <div class="row">
{# "gallery" block #}
            {% elseif block.type == "gallery" %}
                            <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">

                                <section>
                                    <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="someimagesoon.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                    <header>
                                        <h3>{{ block.imageHeader }}</h3>
                                    </header>
                                    <p>{{ block.imageText }}</p>
                                </section>
{# In this place block "gallery" should end #}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <footer class="major">
                            <ul class="buttons">
                                <li><a href="#" class="button">See More</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </footer>

                    </section>

            </article>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather vaguely but if I'm right:

You could put an "if" statement around your "h1" element like,

```
{% if loop.first %}<h1>This text will only be used if the lightswitch is active</h1>{% endif %}
```

Or add a field to the block. Preferably a lightswitch. Which if enabled will show the H1 tag and wont if you dont activate it.

```
{% if block.lightSwitch %}<h1>This text will only be used in the first loop</h1>{% endif %}
```

Comment: Seems like putting my code into {% if loop.first %}{% endif %} makes it just hidden. All I want is to prevent it from being part of the block.

Comment: @J.Baptiste Should try the light switch code but can you be more clear with your question?

Comment: i just edited first post